# Why can't I simply change the bound of integrations for this integral to calculate $<p^2>$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, hilbert-space, integration

If I have the wave function $\psi(x)=\sqrt{\alpha}e^{-\alpha|x|}$, 
why can't I simply change the bounds of integration when I calculate $\langle p^2 \rangle$ such that
$$\langle P^2\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi^*(x) \left(-\hbar^2 \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\psi(x)\right)dx $$
$$=2 \int_{0}^{\infty}\psi^*(x) \left(-\hbar^2 \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\psi(x)\right)dx $$ 
to get rid of the $|x|$. Everywhere online, I see people seperating into two functions instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here you must be careful about the $\delta$-function at the origin:
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} e^{-\alpha|x|}
= e^{-\alpha|x|} \left[ \alpha^2 - 2 \alpha \, \delta(x) \right]\;.$$
The first term generates double the integral from $[0,\infty)$, whereas the second is integrated according to the definition of the $\delta$-function.

Comment: So would it be correct to state that I can't simply split into the two integrals until I first calculate <p>^2 * my function because they are coupled?

Comment: I wouldn't split into two until part way through the calculation, when I'm sure the delta has been correctly accounted for.  You could split into two half deltas, but that's confusing.